# Laravel Blade Layouts

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

This is the problem, its not reading @layout()

[image: its not reading]

Inside the folder View/authors/index.blade.php

> @layout('layouts.default')
>
> @section('content')
>
> ## Authors Home Page
>
> @endsection

In the folder Controllers/authors.php

> class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller{
>
> ```
>   public $restful = true;
>
>   public function get_index(){
>       return View::make('authors.index')->with('title', 'Autores e Livros');
>   }
> ```
>
> }

and inside the folder View/layouts/default.blade.php

basic html

```
<html>
<head> <title> {{ $title }} </title> </head>
<body>
{{ $content }}
</body>
</html>
```

Where's my error? why is it not reading?

[image: Folder]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: Inside View/layouts/default.blade.php

```
<html>
<head> <title> {{ $title }} </title> </head>
<body>
  @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

And second: **Update**

I'm like 99% sure that '@layout('layouts.default')' in your View/authors/index.blade.php is not on the first line. It has to be at the top of the page.

Comment: THANK YOU, +1 for this:

*"@layout('layouts.default')' in your View/authors/index.blade.php is not on the first line. It has to be at the top of the page"*

I've just spent the last 2 hours wondering why my layout wasn't rendering. I can't find this crucial piece of information stated anywhere in the docs or any tutorials. I think this must be about the only place on the internet where this information actually resides.

Comment: I too came across this issue. backspaced and it started to work. Would you know if this is a quirk of laravel 4?

Answer (score 3):

It seems in Laravel 4 you should use *@extends('layouts.default')* instead of *@layout('layouts.default')*

Comment: In his case he is using Laravel 3. You could have recognized it by the snake case style instead of camel case.